# Fundemental theorem of calculus for the second time

Tags: calculus, integration

I have asked a previous question on here, and following their advice I think I understand how to use the FTC for the same type or problem, e.g: $F(x) \int_a^b g(t) dt$

But here I have:

> Find a function $g$ such that $\int_0^x tg(t) \; dt = x + x^2$

Here is my attempt(trying to follow the form of Clarinetist's (fully correct) answer):

$$\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac d{dx} (G(x) - g(0))$$
$$=G'(x) - G'(x)$$
$$=x^2 g(x)=x^2 + x$$
$$g(x) = 1 + \frac1x$$

Is that right, or how do I do it right here. Sorry about aligning equations, don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @PeterFranek I can't see where I mistakenly dropped the $-\frac12$ or whatever to lower $1$ to $\frac12$

Comment: @PeterFranek Actually I might have it, I will edit

Comment: sorry, I mixed it, wanted to say $2+\frac{1}{x}$, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just differentiate your equation wrt. $x$ to get 
$$
x\,g(x)=1+2x
$$
(recall that $\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) dt=f(x)$).

That is, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}+2$. (To be sure that the left and right hand side don't differ by a nonzero constant, check that they agree for $x=0$: $\int_0^0 \ldots = 0+0^2$.)

Comment: Your recall part actually is a nicer way for me to read it than I have anywhere else! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $H(x)=\int_{0}^{x} t g(t) dt$, by FTC $H(x)=F(x)-F(0)$, where $F$- antiderivative of $tg(t)$, so $F(x)-F(0)=x^2+x$ ,then $F'(x)=2x+1$ but $F'(t)=tg(t)$ by FTC:

$2t+1=tg(t)$, finally $g(t)=2+\frac{1}{t}$